# Date changes when using the DateTime class and the modify() method

Tags: php, datetime

Im feeling my way around the \DateTime class which is native to PHP but I have found a peculiar habit.

```
$date = new \DateTime(date('d-m-Y',time())); //this being todays date 21-03-2017

$first = $date->modify('first day of this month');
var_dump($first); //returns ["date"] => string(26) "2017-03-01..."
$last = $date->modify('last day of this month');
var_dump($first); //returns ["date"] => string(26) "2017-03-31..."
```

It appears to assigned by reference and thus gets modified later. How can I prevent this.

Comment: Well, you're doing `var_dump($first)` twice.  Think you want `$last` in the 2nd case  ;)

Comment: You can `clone` object.

Comment: Or use DateTimeImmutable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method [DateTime::modify](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) (add and sub also) is to modify the class (don't to create a new own). As you can see on the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php#refsect1-datetime.modify-examples):

```
$date = new DateTime('2006-12-12');
$date->modify('+1 day');

echo $date->format('Y-m-d');//2006-12-13
```

When you assign the returned date with a new variable, you're assigning only a reference. Wich means that both variables are looking to the same object in memory.

```
$date = new DateTime('2006-12-12');
$nextDay = $date->modify('+1 day');

echo $date->format('Y-m-d');//2006-12-13
echo $nextDay->format('Y-m-d');//2006-12-13
```

If you want to change a `DateTime` without modifying the object (creating a new one) use [DateTimeImmutable](http://php.net/manual/en/datetimeimmutable.modify.php)

```
$date = new DateTimeImmutable('2006-12-12');
$nextDay = $date->modify('+1 day');

echo $date->format('Y-m-d');//2006-12-12
echo $nextDay->format('Y-m-d');//2006-12-13
```

Another approach is with `clone` keyword:

```
$first = clone $last = new \DateTime(date('d-m-Y',time())); //this being todays date 21-03-2017

$first->modify('first day of this month');
var_dump($first);

$last->modify('last day of this month');
var_dump($last);
```

Code: https://3v4l.org/rO7Zd
Result:

```
object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2017-03-01 00:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(16) "Europe/Amsterdam"
}
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2017-03-31 00:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(16) "Europe/Amsterdam"
}
```